# Why is the rate of energy conducted in a rod equals the rate of energy released from the surface at the other end?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, convection, cooling

[image]

Assuming energy is released as convection only,we always do questions by equalizing,
$$P_{\text{conducting}} = Q/t = KA (T1 - T2)/L = eA(dT).$$
Assume the system is at Steady State. Why does this happen and what happens if they are not equal, will the temperature keep on increasing?

Answer (score 1):

The steady state heat equation assumes that the temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$ are, in some manner, held constant. In other words, the temperatures of the warmer body and cooler body in your diagram are fixed. Then once steady state is reached, there will be a constant temperature gradient between the bodies.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The rate of heat flow in a material depends on the rate at which the temperature changes from point to point.  You are usually concerned with equilibrium conditions which occur after the energy has distributed itself to give a temperature gradient that maintains continuity of flow.